# Sequelize Nested- Get Parent Object of child node in nested include

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

```
   Model - Member :- 
          {id: 1,roleId:2,accountId:2,userId:2}

   Model Role :-
          {id:3,accountId:2,title:'Admin',description:'Operations'}

   Model MemberRole :- 
         {id:1,memberId:1,roleId:3}
```

Member has many memberRole
Role has many memberRole

MemberRole belongs Member
MemberRole belongs Role

Now I am fetching Member by id :1
Result Expected

```
Member :{
        id: 1,
        roleId:2,
        accountId:2,
       userId:2
       MemberRole :{
              id:1,
              memberId:1,
              roleId:3
             Role:{
                id:3,
                accountId:2,
                title:'Admin',
                description:'Operations'
               }
             }
    }
```

How to do ? I am newbie to sequelize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at [Basics of queries involving associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#basics-of-queries-involving-associations) in the official documentation?
In your case this could look like this

```js
const member = await Member.findOne({
  where: {
    id: 1
  },
  include: [{
    model: MemberRole,
    include: [{
      model: Role
    }]
  }]
});
```

Be aware that the `MemberRole` prop will be an array of `MemberRole` model instances because you have `M:N` relationship between `Member` and `Role` through the `MemberRole` junction table/model.

Comment: I did the same but role model was missing

Comment: What do you mean? In a result object?